# Раскритиковал за отношение к Таджикистану(,) как в СССР

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

["Мы хотим, чтобы нас уважали". Эмомали Рахмон раскритиковал Путина за отношение к Таджикистану и Центральной Азии **как** в СССР](https://www.currenttime.tv/a/rahmon-raskritikoval-putina-za-otnoshenie-k-tj-i-ca-kak-v-sssr/32084502.html)

В заголовке статьи запятой перед "как" нет. А правильно ли это?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что отсутствие запятой можно объяснить тем, что под словами "как в СССР" автор подразумевает значение [**"по-советски"**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/215528/%D0%9F%D0%BE) (наречие качественно-обстоятельственное; так, как характерно для советских людей или для советской власти).

*По-советски* — как принято в СССР, как свойственно СССР, как характерно для него.

Оборот с союзом "как" не обособляется, если в предложении он выступает в роли обстоятельства образа действия, например: *Тропинка извивалась как змея.* В таких случаях оборот с "как" можно заменить наречием (*по-змеиному*) или существительным в творительном падеже (*змеей*).

[Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183)

Comment: Будет ли постановка запятой ошибкой?

Comment: А вы уверены, что здесь не ошибка? Здесь это: *как было в СССР*. "По-советски" не клеится, если подставить. Да и для такого обстоятельства нужен глагол, а его нет. А дальше идёт такое предложение, и тоже без запятой: *Президент Таджикистана Эмомали Рахмон сказал президенту России Владимиру Путину не вести политику в отношении стран Центральной Азии как в бывшем Советском Союзе.* Тоже нормально?

Comment: Римма, ваш ход. Или вам всё равно на то, правильный ответ или нет?

Comment: Да не все равно, конечно, — иссомневалася вся. Согласна, уж очень хочется поставить запятые. А притянутые уши больно хлипковаты.

Comment: Тогда ответ надо **исправить** и оформить как-то так: *Думаю, что автор не поставил запятую, потому что посчитал, что здесь обстоятельство **образа действия**. Но здесь так не получается, потому что **самого действия нет**, и запятая нужна.* Хотя мне не кажется, что он так посчитал. Скорее всего, просто не знал, что надо поставить запятую. Возможно, у них просто нет денег на корректора. Иногда рассчитывают на грамотность самих авторов.

Comment: Римма, не бросайте так ответы. Вы не раз так делали, но надо становиться лучше, исправляться.

Comment: Не бросаю, становлюсь лучше, исправляюсь... Еще немного помозгую — как же ж поприличней да пограмотней извертеться?